# How to get Wii U to connect to SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: wii-u, wifi

I have tried to get my Wii U to connect to a SOCKS5 proxy. But when I run the connection test the "Internet" part fails with code 103-2101. My SOCKS5 proxy server is srelay. I can connect to it on my computer using Proxifier. Can the Wii U connect to a socks5 proxy? If so, how?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated [here](https://gbatemp.net/threads/can-the-wiiu-use-socks5-proxys.347479/) and other forums, the Wii U cannot connect to socks5 proxies (I believe it only supports standard HTTP proxies). If you are still having issues with Error Code 103-2101, you can read [this Nintendo support page](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=103-2101&system=Wiiu&locale=lang), which states to:

- Review the Wii U proxy server settings.
- Ensure your Internet connection is working.
- Check for wireless interference.

If your purpose is to boost your Wii U's networking and download performance, you can also read [this helpful link](http://thewiiu.com/topic/7948-two-things-that-speedup-wii-u-downloads/), which suggests:

> **1.** Use a proxy server. To do this you need a PC or Mac to run the proxy server on. You may be able to use one on the Internet but I suspect this will not actually speed anything up, as its not the Internet speed which is the problem, its something to do with how the Wii U is actually downloading the files. To do this lookup the instructions for how to speedup PS3 downloads, its exactly the same method and I already had one setup for my PS Vita, I just used the same settings on the Wii U.
>
> **2.** Grab yourself an external USB HDD, connect it to the Wii U and go to System Settings, Data Management, Format USB Storage Device. This WILL delete everything on the HDD so make sure there is nothing you need on there first. Once you have done this the Wii U will automatically use the HDD for downloads rather than the internal memory.

Note that when it suggests the use of a proxy server, it does not recommend socks5.

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there a way to set up a hotspot using SOCKS5? I can't use internet on the Wii U without it because of the firewall.

Comment: I do not think so, due to the Wii U not natively supporting socks5. I would check with your internet service provider or system admin to work around the firewall